# Escaping regex in capture group

Tags: java, regex

I have to extract a part of the string

say the string is

```
    "this is a string "xyz" "
```

what i want to extract from here is the string

```
    xyz
```

But the problem is i have 2 variants of the same string.

```
"this is a string "xyz" "
"this is a string - "
```

i want to extract

```
    xyz or -
```

i've tried a extractor

```
    ".*((?:")[^"]*(?:")|-).*".r
```

this extracts - well and it extracts the string as well but i does not exclude the quotes.
the result i get when i give the 2 string as mentioned above are as follows

```
    "xyz" instead of xyz
    - as expected
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use a matching group or a lookahead/behind.

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit more in details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**, i.e. replace:

```
(?:")[^"]*(?:")
```

with

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?=")
```

`(?<=")` is positive look-behind, checking that the previous character is a `"`, but doesn't include it in the match.
`(?=")` is positive look-ahead, checking that the next character is a `"`, but doesn't include it in the match.

**If you're searching for this inside a larger string**, you may also want to **replace `.*` with `.*?`**. `.*?` will match as few characters as possible, where `.*` will match as many as possible. As an example, given `abbbaabbba`:

```
a.*a  finds abbbaabbba as one match
a.*?a finds abbba and abbba separately
```

These changes introduces a new problem though, as the look-around can try to match the outer braces, whereas a normal match couldn't. If you **replace the `.*`'s with `.+`**, it should prevent this problem (assuming this is valid for the `-` match, the quotes match should be the same because of using look-around).

**Final regex:**

```
".+((?<=")[^"]*(?=")|-).+"
```

I'm not sure what the `.r` was for.

[Test](https://ideone.com/WglI9i).

Comment: that will solve the problem but introduces a new problem and that is an `-` is not been detected now.

Comment: Thanks a tone that solved my problem. The `.r` was to make it an compiled regex object. Thanks once again. @Dukeling

Answer (score 0):

if the one you gave was working for you then this one should work fine

```
(?<=").*((?:")[^"]*(?:")|-).*(?=")
```

in this I have used the look ahead and behind they will match the " in the starting and end but won't include it in the answer.

Comment: I think number of braces is what stopping you, they are not matching in the regex you gave. you looked into it?

Comment: i checked the regX that i provided and used the same two strings and they work fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

For the examples you provided, you dont need anything like a look around.

You can simple use a backreference to ensure that everything that is "wrapping" your target is a `"` - or nothing:

`^this is a ("|)([^"\s]+)(\1)\s*$`

Whenever there are `"` around the next string, they will be NOT part of the match.
If there are no quotes, this parts of the pattern are ignored. The backreference at the end just ensures, that we dont match something like **this is a string "xy** (it tells: WHENEVER there is a leading `"` - we need a trailing one.)

http://regex101.com/r/cU1xM6

Comment: Since the regex doesn't use that fact that the prefix is "this is a string", it's likely that the prefix can change, thus hardcoding it into the regex won't work.

Comment: I took that as an example, meaning that the TCs given string always starts with the same part.